# SQL query add multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sum

I have a problem about adding multiple column values from another table and return as an added column to the result.

Here is my first table.

```
    attID  |  val1   | val2    |   val3   |   att   |
-----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
    1      |   10    |   10    |   10     |    P    |
    1      |   20    |   20    |   20     |    M    |
    1      |   30    |   30    |   30     |    HA   |
    2      |   1     |   1     |    1     |    P    |
    2      |   2     |   2     |    2     |    M    |
    2      |   3     |   3     |    3     |    HA   |
```

My second table is

```
    ID   |  name  | attID   |
---------+--------+---------+  
    101  |  luke  |   1     |
    102  |  zik   |   2     |
```

The result I want is:

```
ID   |  name  |       P      |    M     |     HA     |
-----+--------+--------------+----------+------------+
101  |  luke  |      30      |   60     |     90     |
102  |  zik   |       3      |    6     |      9     |
```

Columns val1 val2 and val3 is added by att, and added to the result table as another column

Here is my solution

```
select 
    ID, Name, 
    (val1 + val2 + val3) P,
    (val1 + val2 + val3) M,
    (val1 + val2 + val3) HA
from
    t1, t2 
where 
    t1.attid = t2.addid 
group by 
    att
```

i tried so many times but can't figure out a solution

thanks in advance if anyone can give me real solution

Comment: Please post an example of what you've tried and what the result was

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `join`, aggregation, and some arithmetic:

```
select t2.ID, t2.name ,
       sum(case when att = 'P' then val1 + val2 + val3 end) as P,
       sum(case when att = 'M' then val1 + val2 + val3 end) as M,
       sum(case when att = 'HA' then val1 + val2 + val3 end) as HA
from t2 left join
     t1
     on t2.attId = t1.attId
group by t2.ID, t2.name ;
```

In your example, none of the values are `NULL`.  If this is the case, you want to be careful and use `coalesce()`.  I think I would recommend a subquery:

```
select t2.ID, t2.name ,
       sum(case when att = 'P' then val end) as P,
       sum(case when att = 'M' then val end) as M,
       sum(case when att = 'HA' then val end) as HA
from t2 left join
     (select t1.*,
             (coalesce(val1, 0) + coalesce(val2, 0) + coalesce(va3, 0)
             ) as val
      from t1
     ) t1
     on t2.attId = t1.attId
group by t2.ID, t2.name ;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this would be the best one. but i have an error if i apply this to my real table. the error is saying "not a single-group group funtion",

Comment: @VonAso . . . These queries look correctly formed, particularly from an aggregation perspective.  This error usually occurs when you have an unaggregated column in the `select` that is not in the `group by`.

Comment: @VonAso -  The query is correct, I just tested it (except that the second `att` value is `M` rather than `PM`). `coalesce` doesn't seem like the right solution (it will produce 0 even if all the values are `null`, in which case by **any** reasonable definition the result should be `null`); and the join should be done only after the aggregation, not before, to reduce the cardinality, but this is only about efficiency, not correctness. The query as written is correct and runs fine.

Comment: Yes it worked fine. thank you, and sorry for the late reply